# Elasticsearch client java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError in 5.3

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Following code listed here on [TransportClient](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/5.3/transport-client.html).

Using elasticsearch and client dependencies.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.DeprecationLogger.<clinit>(DeprecationLogger.java:138)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.support.AbstractXContentParser.<init>(AbstractXContentParser.java:57)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.json.JsonXContentParser.<init>(JsonXContentParser.java:44)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.json.JsonXContent.createParser(JsonXContent.java:103)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Setting.parseableStringToList(Setting.java:832)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Setting.lambda$listSetting$27(Setting.java:786)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Setting.listSetting(Setting.java:791)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Setting.listSetting(Setting.java:786)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.network.NetworkService.<clinit>(NetworkService.java:50)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.newPluginService(TransportClient.java:98)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.buildTemplate(TransportClient.java:126)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.<init>(TransportClient.java:268)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.client.PreBuiltTransportClient.<init>(PreBuiltTransportClient.java:125)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.client.PreBuiltTransportClient.<init>(PreBuiltTransportClient.java:111)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.client.PreBuiltTransportClient.<init>(PreBuiltTransportClient.java:101)
    at xxx.test.runner.ESRunner.initESClient(ESRunner.java:120)
    at xxx.test.runner.ESRunner.inti(ESRunner.java:62)
    at xxx.test.runner.ESRunner.main(ESRunner.java:46)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error finding the build shortHash. Stopping Elasticsearch now so it doesn't run in subtly broken ways. This is likely a build bug.
    at org.elasticsearch.Build.<clinit>(Build.java:62)
    ... 18 more
```

Could it missing some dependency, or something else? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had the same problem. use 5.2.2 instead. the problem is (at least for me) that the transportClient of 5.3 reads the manifest file of the jar which isn't possible because the application runs on wildfly (the jar file is on a virtual file system)

Comment: Down grading to 5.2.2 stopped the exception, but now running into other issues. Thanks for suggestion.